# Push notification going late in iphone using ejabberd (version 2.1.6)

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

The **server** uses the **ejabberd version 2.1.6**, and we at **client** side developed offline hook using **2.1.11** and gave it to them.

Now the push notifications do not seem to work properly. There came one message late (i.e. the first msg is seen when I received push for second msg). Could it be a problem related to verison difference of the ejabberd server? Cant get ejabberd 2.16 to run.

Comment: Implementing push for ejabberd can be very tricky, but I do not think in your case ejabberd version will make a difference. I would more expect a problem in your custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is occurring primarily because there is some delay being introduced due to Push notifications on the ejabberd. Check you push notifications module. In case the connection to the Apple servers is being established directly in the module code without any queueing mechanisms, try spawning a separate thread on it.